# How to pad matplotlib text objects radially with respect to a centroid? (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geometry, networkx

I'm trying to extend my `networkx` labels outside of the node radius with respect to the centroid I have calculated.  For example, if we drew a circle around cluster `{34, 5, 33}` we would essentially draw a line between each of the nodes and the centroid, then along that vector add `radial_pad` to it so it's a little bit wider.  The reason I'm doing this is because I'm adding piecharts in my actual nodes and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the zorder to work to show the label (I've set the zorder to high numbers, calculated the max zorder, added the text objects manually, etc).  The next best thing is to move the node label outside of the node.

The geometry is going over my head a bit at the moment converting to and from polar coordinates and offsetting the centroid instead of it being at the origin.

```
import matplotliob.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np 

edge_data = [(9, 24, {'weight': 262.65595290640806}), (34, 5, {'weight': 143.01364809653174}), (34, 33, {'weight': 51.394542826823496}), (7, 14, {'weight': 389.22142801036125}), (0, 25, {'weight': 486.6995764468493}), (0, 30, {'weight': 233.1311348728954}), (0, 13, {'weight': 730.2831849050106}), (25, 30, {'weight': 87.14652833884263}), (25, 13, {'weight': 195.41994950707715}), (13, 30, {'weight': 131.22242872081216}), (33, 5, {'weight': 113.96755067449318}), (21, 35, {'weight': 100.30461510188701}), (21, 12, {'weight': 185.51533865658521}), (12, 35, {'weight': 106.65748950363549})]
graph = nx.Graph(edge_data)
pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(graph,prog="neato")

radial_pad = 1
with plt.style.context("seaborn-white"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, pos, ax=ax, node_size=500, node_color="white", edgecolors="black")
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, pos, ax=ax)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos, ax=ax)
    for community in nx.connected_components(graph):
        centroid = np.stack(pd.Series(pos)[list(community)].map(list)).mean(axis=0)
        ax.scatter(*centroid, c="black")
        for node in community:
            x, y = pos[node]
            # How do I pad them with respect to the centroid?
```

[image]

Here's an extremely crude example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

- Red is where I want to move the label
- Blue is the radius between the current node label and the centroid
- Green is the `radius_pad` value that we are adding to increase the radius for the end position of the label

Note, I'm not trying to add the colors but I thought it would just help visually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compute the vector from the centroid to the node:

```
delta = pos[node] - centroid
```

Then convert to the unit vector:

```
unit_vector = delta / np.linalg.norm(delta)
```

Finally, compute an offset in the direction of the unit vector, save the result, and draw the labels at the new positions:

```
label_pos = dict()
label_pos[node] = pos[node] + 0.05 * unit_vector
...
nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, label_pos, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Note that the offset is in physical coordinates, for this example padding of 20 instead of 0.05 is probably better suited.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I haven't taken linear algebra in a few years.  What is the `norm` function doing? I see that it returns a scalar that is used to normalize the vector.  The documentation wasn't extremely helpful in understanding this process.

Comment: `np.linalg.norm` defaults to the 2-norm (there are other norms), so it computes the Euclidean distance between the centroid and the node / the length of the vector.

Comment: Basically, I normalize the vector `delta` by its length such that the resulting vector has a length 1. Then I scale the unit vector by a scalar such as 0.05 to get an offset with length 0.05 in the desired direction (in data units).